# Not able to send a simple "Hello World" message to RabbitMQ queue using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amqp, spring-rabbit

I am not able to send a message to `RabbitMQ` server using `Spring Boot`. I do not see any exception. Not sure what's going on.

I have admin-level access to the management console of `RabbitMQ` and can see if the queue is getting created or not. But I do not see any queue getting created. Moreover in the console logs all I see is this.

**Console Logs:**

```
2017-08-15 11:32:17.015  INFO 8256 --- [           main] com.study.jms.BasicApplication           : Starting BasicApplication on KOP-DBT0J12 with PID 8256 (C:\NITAL\MY-DATA\CODE-SAMPLES\SPRINGBOOT-MESSAGING-SAMPLES\rabbitmq\rabbitmq-helloworld-producer-demo\target\classes started by chandeln in C:\NITAL\MY-DATA\CODE-SAMPLES\SPRINGBOOT-MESSAGING-SAMPLES\rabbitmq\rabbitmq-helloworld-producer-demo)
2017-08-15 11:32:17.020  INFO 8256 --- [           main] com.study.jms.BasicApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-08-15 11:32:17.112  INFO 8256 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@73d4cc9e: startup date [Tue Aug 15 11:32:17 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-15 11:32:17.915  INFO 8256 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c012f1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-08-15 11:32:18.739  INFO 8256 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-08-15 11:32:18.749  INFO 8256 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-08-15 11:32:18.749  INFO 8256 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'rabbitConnectionFactory': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory]
2017-08-15 11:32:18.769  INFO 8256 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2017-08-15 11:32:18.779  INFO 8256 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2017-08-15 11:32:18.839  INFO 8256 --- [           main] com.study.jms.BasicApplication           : Started BasicApplication in 2.208 seconds (JVM running for 2.668)
2017-08-15 11:32:18.883  INFO 8256 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#2cc44ad:0/SimpleConnection@61f05988 [delegate=amqp://admin@172.25.20.43:5672/, localPort= 65025]
```

**BasicApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BasicApplication {

    private static RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(BasicApplication.class, args);
        rabbitTemplate = ctx.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("helloworld.q", "Hello World !");
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=gsi-547576
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=admin
spring.rabbitmq.password=admin
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you try [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#management-template) and see if you are able to get all the declared queues?

Comment: have you followed this https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/ ?

Comment: @Darshan - Yes, I do get 200 OK response with the queue names

Comment: @Barath - I have gone through that online example and I am sure that if I follow it, it's going to work. But my concern is what's wrong in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing RabbitMQ `Queue` bean definition:

```
@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    return new Queue("helloworld.q", false);
}
```

RabbitMQ **requires** queues to be created before publishing any message to them. One way to do it in Spring Boot is to define `Queue` bean and Spring Boot will handle it's creation. When you add it you will see something like this in your console log:

```
2017-08-15 18:32:16.929  INFO 21163 --- [           main] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (helloworld.q) durable:false, auto-delete:false, exclusive:false. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
```

Of course you can define multiple beans of type `Queue` - all of them will be created. How it's done? `RabbitAdmin` component loads all `Declarable` beans and creates e.g. [queues from Spring beans with type `Queue`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitAdmin.java#L443).

I have just tested following simple Spring Boot app:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("helloworld.q", false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = ctx.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("helloworld.q", "Hello World !");
    }
}
```

And after running here is what I see in RabbitMQ admin:

[image]

[image]

Of course this queue was not created beforehand. I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, this is the same link that `Barath` posted a few mins back. I will look into this. But I have two questions: 1)  My current program has been taken from one of `SpringBoot` `ActiveMQ` example. It worked!. Hence I modified the original program by making two changes in it a) Used `RabbitTemplate` instead of `JmsTemplate` and pointed it to `RabbitMQ` server instead of `ActiveMQ` server b) I did not create any Connection Factory or anything in it and it still worked. 2) The program that you listed above contains a message listener. But what if I am just a publisher. Do I still need one?

Comment: @user2325154 Thanks for more detailed information. I have updated my answer to follow your specific use case. In this case all you have to do is to define `Queue` bean that will be registered by `RabbitAdmin` component during initialization.

Comment: @user2325154 Cool, I'm glad I could help you :)